# Spring Mqtt subscribe from the last read position

Tags: mqtt, spring-integration-mqtt

I am using spring integration Mqtt.
Whenever I restart the app, it starts consuming the message from the 1st position. Is there any property to make app read from last read or current position.

I couldn't find it.

If there is not such a option then there will be problem if down the line a new version is deployed and app starts consuming from 1st position

Below is the code which I am using to test

```
    @Bean
    public MessageChannel mqttInputChannel() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageProducer inbound() {
        MqttPahoMessageDrivenChannelAdapter adapter =
                new MqttPahoMessageDrivenChannelAdapter(clientId, mqttClientFactory(),
                        batteryLevel, locationChange);
        adapter.setCompletionTimeout(5000);
        adapter.setConverter(new DefaultPahoMessageConverter());
        adapter.setQos(1);
        adapter.setOutputChannel(mqttInputChannel());
        adapter.setManualAcks(false);
        return adapter;
    }
    
    @Bean
    public MqttPahoClientFactory mqttClientFactory() {
        DefaultMqttPahoClientFactory factory = new DefaultMqttPahoClientFactory();
        MqttConnectOptions options = new MqttConnectOptions();
        options.setServerURIs(new String[] { serverAddress });
        options.setCleanSession(false);
        factory.setConnectionOptions(options);
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "mqttInputChannel")
    public MessageHandler handler() {
        return new MessageHandler() {

            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message<?> message) throws MessagingException {
                String topic = message.getHeaders().get(MqttHeaders.RECEIVED_TOPIC).toString();
                LOGGER.info("topic : " +topic);
                LOGGER.info(message.getPayload().toString())
               }
          }
```

Comment: Firstly MQTT is not a message queue. Secondly you need to add some more detail here about exactly what you are seeing, best guess is that you have a retained message on the topic.

Comment: I am testing the Mqtt consumer in local and each time I restarts the consumer it starts consuming from the first message which I published for testing. I was hopping that with same client id and clean session as false this will not happen.

Comment: Please edit the question to add detail. An MQTT broker will only queue messages for an existing client when the QOS is greater than 0 and clean session is false. You need to still add a lot more details about exactly how you are running the tests.

Comment: It's working properly now. I think clean session was the issue. If possible, Can you please share some detail on QoS? I need to know if I am setting it correctly